# $root gets overwritten by shallowMount wrapper $root

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

I have a problem with Unit testing a Vue component.

I need to override the `$root` thats created by the `shallowMount` function.

I have a plugin component which is assigning its `$root`s data to its local data:

```
data() {
  return {
    noStoreNotifications: [],
    isHistoryOpen: false,
    pluginSettingWithoutStore: this.$root._pluginSetting.withoutStore,
    pluginSettingShowNotification: this.$root._pluginSetting.showHistory,
    pluginSettingMaxHistoryLength: this.$root._pluginSetting.maxHistoryLength,
    pluginSettingReverseHistory: this.$root._pluginSetting.reverseHistory,
  };
},
```

Since this plugin is used in multiple repositories, with different components and use cases, I need to be able to access its wrapper to get some data from it.

The plugin works fine but the unit test for it is not working as I would expect, but it makes sense why its not working.

As I wrote, I need to access the components wrapper object through `$root`. 
And normally I would use:

```
cosnt data = {
  mocks: {
    $root: {
      _eventHub: new Vue(),
      _notificationContainer: null,
      _pluginSetting: {},
    },
  },
}
```

within the initial mount of the component

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Notifications, data);
```

However this doesnt work, because the `shallowMount` method creates a wrapper with its own unique `$root`, which overrides mine.

Is there a way to override its `$root` to my specification before the component gets created?